# distances between vectors contained in a list in prolog

Tags: list, vector, prolog, distance

I am quite new to prolog and I am trying to write a predicate

```
distance_all(List, List_of_distances).
```

whose input is  a list of list cointaining vector coohordinates:

INPUT = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,7,3],[1,6,3]]

and output a list containing all the distance between each point to the other.

I tought about doing it this way but (sorry the bad pseudo-code).
 I dont really know how to handle it in Prolog!

1. distance(point1, point2) = D_1-2

   distance(point1, point3) = D_1-3

   until distance(point1, last_point) = D_1-last

   distance(point2, point3) = D_2-3

   distance(point2, point4) = D_2-4

   distance(point2, last_point)  = D_2-last
   ans so on...

so the output is like

OUTPUT = [D_1-2, D_1-3,....., D_1-last, D_2-3, D_2-4,..... D_2-last...].

I have already implemented a predicate

distance(Vector1, Vector2, D).

where D is the Euclidean distance between Vector1 and Vector2 (in 2D, 3D or whatever)

---

Another question

What if i want to remember the original vectors that originated the minimum distance?

for example

?- distance_all([[1,1],[1,2],[6,3],[8,2]],Lo).
Lo = [1.0, 5.385164807134504, 7.0710678118654755, 5.0990195135927845, 7.0, 2.23606797749979]

the minimum distance is 1.0... But between wich vectors? lets say were A and B

I need to use another predicate on those A B

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
distance_all_h(_, [], [], []).

distance_all_h(_, [], [Hn | Tn], Lo) :-
  distance_all_h(Hn, Tn, Tn, Lo).

distance_all_h(V, [Hi | Ti], Ln, [Ho | Lo]) :-
  distance(V, Hi, Ho),
  distance_all_h(V, Ti, Ln, Lo).

distance_all([], []).

distance_all([Hi | Ti], Lo) :-
  distance_all_h(Hi, Ti, Ti, Lo).
```

?

When the input list is empty, the output list is empty.

Otherwise, the idea is create a helper clause (distance_all_h/3) that receive

1) the head of the input list

2) the tail of the input list (to calcolate the distances with the head)

3) the tail of the input list again (to restart with the following head when the second argument is consumed)

4) the output list

**--- EDIT ---**

> What if i want to remember the original vectors that originated the
>   minimum distance?

Modified solution to return the minimum distance (third parameter in `distance_all`) and a list of couples of vector that correspond to minimum distance (fourth parameter)

Take in count that more couples of vector can correspond to the same minimum distance.

```
% 1000000000 is intended as a number bigger than every distance
distance_all_h(_, [], [], [], 1000000000, []).

distance_all_h(_, [], [Hn | Tn], Lo, Md, ABl) :-
  distance_all_h(Hn, Tn, Tn, Lo, Md, ABl).

distance_all_h(V, [Hi | Ti], Ln, [Ho | Lo], Ho, [[V, Hi]]) :-
  distance(V, Hi, Ho),
  distance_all_h(V, Ti, Ln, Lo, Dd, _),
  Ho < Dd.

distance_all_h(V, [Hi | Ti], Ln, [Ho | Lo], Dd, ABl) :-
  distance(V, Hi, Ho),
  distance_all_h(V, Ti, Ln, Lo, Dd, ABl),
  Ho > Dd.

distance_all_h(V, [Hi | Ti], Ln, [Ho | Lo], Ho, [[V, Hi] | ABt]) :-
  distance(V, Hi, Ho),
  distance_all_h(V, Ti, Ln, Lo, Ho, ABt).

distance_all([], [], 0, []).

distance_all([Hi | Ti], Lo, Md, ABl) :-
  distance_all_h(Hi, Ti, Ti, Lo, Md, ABl).
```

Answer (score 1):

if your Prolog has library([aggregate](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), and you don't mind about efficiency, you can do

```
distance_min(List, MinDist,P1,P2) :-
    aggregate(min(D,(X,Y)), R^(select(X,List,R),member(Y,R), distance(X,Y,D)), min(MinDist,(P1,P2))).

distance([X1,X2],[Y1,Y2],D) :-
    D is sqrt((Y1-X1)*(Y1-X1)+(Y2-X2)*(Y2-X2)).
distance([X1,X2,X3],[Y1,Y2,Y3],D) :-
    D is sqrt((Y1-X1)*(Y1-X1)+(Y2-X2)*(Y2-X2)+(Y3-X3)*(Y3-X3)).

?- distance_min([[1,1],[1,2],[6,3],[8,2]],D,X,Y).
D = 1.0,
X = [1, 1],
Y = [1, 2].
```

Answer (score 1):

A moderately short and basic way to write it, without `findall` and `aggregate` and so on goes something like this.

First, a predicate that finds the Euclidean distance between two lists of coordinates:

```
d([P|Ps], [Q|Qs], D) :-
        sum_diff_sq(Ps, Qs, (P-Q)^2, R),
        D is sqrt(R).

sum_diff_sq([], [], V, V).
sum_diff_sq([P|Ps], [Q|Qs], V0, V+V0) :-
        sum_diff_sq(Ps, Qs, (P-Q)^2, V).
```

This will calculate the distance between a pair of coordinates, each a list of numbers.

```
?- d([1], [1], D).
D = 0.0.

?- d([1], [2], D).
D = 1.0.

?- d([1,1], [2,2], D).
D = 1.4142135623730951.

?- d([1,1,1], [2,2,2], D).
D = 1.7320508075688772.

?- d([1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], D).
D = 2.0.
```

Then, to calculate all possible distances:

```
points_distances([], []).
points_distances([P|Ps], Ds) :-
        rest_distances(Ps, P, Ds, Ds0),
        points_distances(Ps, Ds0).
```

`points_distances/2` makes a list of distances between the head and each of the coordinates in the tail of a list, recursively (so at the the distance between each pair will be in the result).

```
rest_distances([], _, Back, Back).
rest_distances([P|Ps], X, [D|Ds], Back) :-
        d(P, X, D),
        rest_distances(Ps, X, Ds, Back).
```

This simply calculates the distances between a list of coordinates and a coordinate. The result is a difference list.

To use this:

```
?- points_distances([[1,1],[1,2],[6,3],[8,2]], D).
D = [1.0, 5.385164807134504, 7.0710678118654755, 5.0990195135927845, 7.0, 2.23606797749979].

?- points_distances([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,7,3],[1,6,3]], D).
D = [1.7320508075688772, 5.0, 4.0, 4.242640687119285, 3.3166247903554, 1.0].
```

If you wanted, you could "save" which pair of coordinates are at a distance of each other. For example, change the head of the second clause of `rest_distances/4` from:

```
rest_distances([P|Ps], X, [D|Ds], Back)
```

to:

```
rest_distances([P|Ps], X, [D-pq(X,P)|Ds], Back)
```

Now, after reloading the program, you can sort the result of `points_distances/2` and take the first element in it, just like in the other answer:

```
?- points_distances( [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,7,3],[1,6,3]] , D),
   keysort(D, [Min_dist-pq(P,Q)|_]).
D = [1.7320508075688772-pq([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]),
     5.0-pq([1, 2, 3], [1, 7, 3]),
     4.0-pq([1, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3]),
     4.242640687119285-pq([2, 3, 4], [1, 7, 3]),
     3.3166247903554-pq([2, 3|...], [1, 6|...]),
     1.0-pq([1|...], [1|...])],
Min_dist = 1.0,
P = [1, 7, 3],
Q = [1, 6, 3].
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
distance_all(Input_list,Output_list):-
         findall(L,combinations(Input_list,L),List),
         find_distances(List,Output_list).

combinations([],[]).
combinations(Lin,[Vector1,Vector2]):-choose(Vector1,Lin,L),choose(Vector2,L,_).

choose(H,[H|T],T).
choose(H1,[_|T],T1):-choose(H1,T,T1).

find_distances([],[]).
find_distances([[Vector1,Vector2]|T],[D|T1]):-
         distance(Vector1,Vector2,D),
         find_distances(T,T1).
```

UPDATE

for the second question you could change:

```
find_distances([],[]).
find_distances([[Vector1,Vector2]|T],[D-[Vector1,Vector2]|T1]):-
             distance(Vector1,Vector2,D),
             find_distances(T,T1).
```

So instead of returning the list of distances, it will be encoded so that every element will be in the form of: `D-[Vector-n,Vector-m]`

To find min distance use keysort/2:

```
distance_all(Input_list,Output_list):-
         findall(L,combinations(Input_list,L),List),
         find_distances(List,L1),
         keysort(L1,L2),
         find_distances2(L2,Output_list).
```

Keysort sort the list so the first element will have min d and you can take it by adding above for example: `L1=[Dmin-[Vector1,Vector2]|_]`.

since the list L1 has the form explained above , in order to get the output list of your first question you could simple keep only distances in the output list by writing:

```
find_distances([],[]).
find_distances([D-[Vector1,Vector2]|T],[D|T1]):-find_distances(T,T1).
```